# How to iterate JSON data in Android

Tags: java, android, json, togglebutton

```
{   "gb": [
    {
      "omrid": "gis-n",
      "status": 0,
      "grupp": 1
    },
    {
      "omrid": "gis-s",
      "status": 0,
      "grupp": 1
    },
    {
      "omrid": "gis-c",
      "status": 0,
      "grupp": 1
    },
    {
      "omrid": "gis-h",
      "status": 0,
      "grupp": 1
    },
    {
      "omrid": "gis-g",
      "status": 0,
      "grupp": 1
    },
    {
      "omrid": "hes",
      "status": 0,
      "grupp": 2
    }   ] }
```

This above is my JSON String (edited shorter because it became too long here).

I'm trying to find a way to be able to iterate each group and create a togglebutton with them.

So what I'm trying to do is create a togglebutton with the name stated in "omrid" with the on/off status of "status". The "grupp" is for future use eventually to sort the toggles into groups but not important now.

I have searched and searched about this and noone seems to have my specific JSON string composition and I'm a bit of a noob with JSON/Android SDK.

Comment: @Waqas StackOverflow is an international site. Please write comments in English and not Swedish :)

Comment: What Waqas said translated: Read more about Json [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-json-tutorials/)

Comment: Det gör jag. just got a little over excited by seeing some swedish fellows :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `JSONObject`. THer is no difference where you run in on Android or PC.

```
String str = "{" + 
            "    \"gb\": [" + 
            "        {" + 
            "            \"omrid\": \"gis-n\"," + 
            "            \"status\": 0," + 
            "            \"grupp\": 1" + 
            "        }," + 
            "        {" + 
            "            \"omrid\": \"gis-s\"," + 
            "            \"status\": 0," + 
            "            \"grupp\": 1" + 
            "        }," + 
            "        {" + 
            "            \"omrid\": \"gis-c\"," + 
            "            \"status\": 0," + 
            "            \"grupp\": 1" + 
            "        }," + 
            "        {" + 
            "            \"omrid\": \"gis-h\"," + 
            "            \"status\": 0," + 
            "            \"grupp\": 1" + 
            "        }," + 
            "        {" + 
            "            \"omrid\": \"gis-g\"," + 
            "            \"status\": 0," + 
            "            \"grupp\": 1" + 
            "        }," + 
            "        {" + 
            "            \"omrid\": \"hes\"," + 
            "            \"status\": 0," + 
            "            \"grupp\": 2" + 
            "        }" + 
            "    ]" + 
            "}";

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);

    JSONArray gb = jsonObject.getJSONArray("gb");

    for (int j = 0; j < gb.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject element = gb.getJSONObject(j);

        int status = element.getInt("status");
        int grupp = element.getInt("grupp");
        String omrid = element.getString("omrid");

        System.out.println("status=" + status + "; grupp=" + grupp + "; omrid=" + omrid);

//create togglebutton here
    }
```

Output:

```
status=0; grupp=1; omrid=gis-n
status=0; grupp=1; omrid=gis-s
status=0; grupp=1; omrid=gis-c
status=0; grupp=1; omrid=gis-h
status=0; grupp=1; omrid=gis-g
status=0; grupp=2; omrid=hes
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I was running loads of tests and got to this solution 1 minute ago, u beat me to the punch ;)

Answer (score 0):

here's the code

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(String your_json_string);
JSONArray arr = json.getJSONArray("gb");
for(int i = 0;i<arr.length();i++)
{
JSONObject temp = arr.getJSONObject(i);
temp.getString("omrid");//use them as your needs
temp.getString("status");//use them as your needs
temp.getString("grupp");//   use them as your needs
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to iterate.

Make one class JSONParser as below.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONParser {

    public JSONParser() {

    }

    JSONObject jObj;
    String json;
    InputStream is = null;

    public JSONObject getJsonFromUrl(String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();

            System.out.println("Json String : " + json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

In your MainActivity use following to iterate.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject o = parser.getJsonFromUrl("yourjsonurl");

JSONArray array = o.getJSONArray("gb");

for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
    JSONObject j = array.getJSONObject(i);

    String omrid = j.getString("omrid");
    String status= j.getString("status");
    String grupp = j.getString("grupp");
}
```